# Geometric intuition of perpendicular complex vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, complex-numbers

I want to grasp the idea of orthogonality and angle between complex vectors. Some things are very confusing to me like if i take a vector in $\mathbf{C}^1$ (say $a+\iota b$) and it's conjugate $a - \iota b$ then the the dot product is always $> 0$ and using the standard equation for angle can claim it can never be orthogonal.

However my mind immediately tries to think $1+ \iota$ and $1- \iota$ in complex plane and how they are perpendicular in the complex plane geometrically.

So what is the right way to view complex vectors geometrically ?

Comment: Can you clarify what definition of complex dot product you're using? Are you using $(x + i y) \cdot (x' + i y') = xx' + yy'$, or something else?

Comment: He's using the standard inner product on $C^n$ which is $\langle u, v \rangle = v^*u$. Here $v^*$ is the conjugate transpose of the column vector $v \in \mathbb C^n$.

Comment: You would not expect the vector $1 + i \in C^1$ to be orthogonal to itself. And indeed, $\langle 1+i, 1+ i \rangle = (1+i)(1-i) = 2 \neq 0$.

Comment: @Siddharth Bhat yes the standard inner product definition and the one clarified in  comments ($v^*u$)

Comment: @littleO yes i would not expect $1 + \iota$ to be orthogonal to itself.
However I expect $1 + \iota$ and $1 - \iota$ to be orthogonal which turn out to be $(1+\iota)^2 \neq 0$

Comment: In my mind, the inner product in $\mathbb C^n$ is defined so that the properties we desire of an inner product are satisfied. I don't have a way of visualizing vectors in $\mathbb C^n$ or their inner products. When I work with vectors in $\mathbb C^n$, I'm visualizing vectors in $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$ and working by analogy, I would say.

Comment: The *real part* of the hermitian inner product gives the real dot product you're expecting. The imaginary part is skew-symmetric and gives a $2$-form called the Kähler form on the complex vector space.